# How to set data to an empty QTableView cell

Tags: qt

```
Connection conn;
model = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
QString query;
model->setQuery(query, conn.db);

ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

The cells I want to populate with data are in column that I added myself doesn't belong to db
of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QSqlQueryModel` is read-only. Write your own custom model, or fill `QStandardItemModel` with items you got from `QSqlQuery`and add your own items.